# Loop through folder and join pairs of files with the same prefix

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins, loop

I have two sets of shapefiles that I would like to join based on a similar field. They are all stored in a path folder which is stored as the variable "steps".

One group of shapefiles are polygon shapefiles named something like "polygonA_footprints.shp", "polygonB_footprints.shp" , "polygonC_footprints.shp"

The other group are a set of points shapefile named something like "polygonA_points.shp" "polygonB_points.shp", "polygonC_points.shp"

Both groups have the same field "PID".

I'd like to join the .dbf table from the points.shp layer to their matched polygon.shp.

The following is my code:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = steps
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
shplist = arcpy.ListFiles("*footprints.shp")
tablelist = arcpy.ListFiles("*points.dbf")
for shp in shplist:
    sprefix = shp.rsplit("*footprints.shp")[0]
for t in tablelist:
        tprefix = t.rsplit("*points.dbf")[0]
if sprefix == tprefix:
        arcpy.AddJoin_management(shp,"PID",t,"PID")
```

Running the code in PyCharm does not produce any error messages, however when I open the polygon.shp in ArcMap the join is not complete. I've tried using "*footprints.dbf" and "*footprints.shp" in Line 3 and experimented with my indentations of the 'for' lines to no avail.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? I have also tried:

```
        arcpy.env.workspace = steps
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
        shplist = arcpy.ListFiles("*footprints.shp")
        tablelist = arcpy.ListFiles("*geotagswBearings.dbf")
        for shp in shplist:
          sprefix = shp.rsplit("*footprints.shp")[0]
             for t in tablelist:
                    tprefix = t.rsplit("*geotagswBearings.dbf")[0]
            if sprefix == tprefix:
                arcpy.AddJoin_management(shp,"PID",t,"PID")
```

and:

```
        arcpy.env.workspace = steps
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
        shplist = arcpy.ListFiles("*footprints.shp")
        tablelist = arcpy.ListFiles("*geotagswBearings.dbf")
        for shp in shplist:
            for t in tablelist:
                    sprefix = shp.rsplit("*footprints.shp")[0]
                    tprefix = t.rsplit("*geotagswBearings.dbf")[0]
                    if sprefix == tprefix:
                        arcpy.AddJoin_management(shp,"PID",t,"PID")
```

and I've also tried substituting "*footprints.dbf" for "*footprints.shp" as I thought it might need the input_layer table instead of feature class based on the Desktop help section (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-join.htm)

Comment: This is more a Python coding logic issue than anything ArcPy specific. Generally speaking, you want to nest your searching.

Comment: @Vince, I am new to Python. How should I be formatting to do nesting? I've edited my question to show different types of nesting I was trying.

Comment: Add Join just adds a join to a layer in memory, it doesn't permanently join the fields to the dataset. If that's what you want to do, use the "Join Fields" tool.

Comment: Do you have the same number of features classes? A-A B-B, never C-None

Comment: Thanks all. @BERA yes I do have the same number of feature classes. The issue was four-fold: I needed to use JoinField_management instead of AddJoin as user2856 suggested. I needed to join a table to a table, not a shapefile to a table, I needed to nest looks Vince said. And the sprefix ==prefix was returning FALSE because my rsplit was returning the different file extensions as well. Thanks all.